# GLUT and draw commands not drawing

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, glut

I recently redesigned my application so that the data collection is done in the Idle function. The program reads in a file from argv[1] and parses out commands from that file. That portion all seems to work with no issues and the parsed data is accurate.

The issue lies in the display function. The command 'cone' gets called (right now thats the only command in my file), and that is shown in the console output. But the cone is not showing on the canvas. Ive also attempted to put the draw command for the cone outside of the loop to see if that have any affect (and it did not).

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <gl\glew.h>
#include <gl\freeglut.h>
#include <gl\GLU.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void makeLower(char *input);
void extractVals(char *cmd, double *val);

FILE *file;
int g_mainWindow = -1;
float g_lightPos[] = {1, 1, -1, 0};
char commands [50][50];
int fileSize = -1;

void idle()
{   
  /* parse a command from file */
  /* store the data for later draw */
    char linebyline [50], *lineStr = linebyline;
    int i=0;

    while(!feof(file) && file != NULL){
        fgets(lineStr , 50, file);
        makeLower(lineStr);
        strcpy(commands[i] , lineStr);
        fileSize = i;
        i++;
    }

    glutSetWindow(g_mainWindow);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void makeLower(char *input)
{
    while (*input != '\0')
    {
        *input = tolower(*input);
        input++;
    }
}

/*
    Using a tolenizer this extracts out values needed for other functions to draw.
*/
void extractVals(char *cmd, float *val){
    int i=0;
    cmd = strtok(NULL, " ,");
    while(cmd != NULL){
        val[i] = atof(cmd);
        cmd = strtok(NULL, " ,");
        i++;
    }
    val[4] = i--;
}



void display()
{
    int i;
    char cmdTok[10] , *cmd = cmdTok;
    float val[5];

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    for(i = 0 ; i <= fileSize ; i++){
        cmd = strtok(commands[i] , " \n\0");
            switch(*cmd){
                case 'g'://translate object
                    extractVals(cmd , val);
                    glTranslatef(val[0] , val[1] , val[2]);
                    break;
                case 's'://scales an object
                    extractVals(cmd , val);
                    if (val[4] == 1.){
                        glScalef(val[0],val[0],val[0]);
                    }
                    else if (val[4] == 3.){
                        glScalef(val[0] , val[1] , val [2]);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'r'://rotates an object
                    break;
                case 'c'://this can call draw cone , cube, or change colors.
                    if(strcmp(cmd , "cone") == 0){
                        printf("drawing a cone\n");
                        glutSolidCone(.5 , 1 , 8, 1);
                    } else if (strcmp(cmd , "cube") == 0){
                        glutSolidCube(1);
                    } else if (*cmd == 'c'){
                        extractVals(cmd , val);
                        glColor3f(val[0] , val[1], val[2]);
                    }
                    break;
                case 't'://draw a torus or tea pot
                    break;
                case 'o'://reads a meshfile
                    break;
                case 'f'://save current frame buffer.
                    break;
                case 'm':
                    break;
            }

    }

    glutSolidCone(.5 , 1 , 8, 1);
    glFlush();
    // also consider glutSwapBuffers for smoothness
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    float aspect = w / (float)h;

    glViewport(0,0,w,h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-aspect, aspect, -1, 1, -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

   glutInit(&argc, argv);
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
   g_mainWindow = glutCreateWindow("Hello, glut");
   glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, g_lightPos);

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);



    glutMainLoop();
   fclose(file);
}
```

Looks like it had to do with imports. I added a few lines fo code and it seems to have worked.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <gl/glu.h>
```

and in display I added

```
glutSwapBuffers();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0.0, width, 0.0, height, -1, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

right before your `glutMainLoop()` (where width and height are the width and height of the window)?

I haven't done Windows OpenGL so feel free to correct me if something should be different.

Comment: I think those commands are being called in reshape. I think that sufficient? Im not 100% on that though.

Comment: @meriley I don't think reshape gets called until the window gets resized. Not 100% on this though, but this fixed some code that I used with an idlefunc to display.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help, still :(

Comment: @meriley Is there a reason for using GLUT_DEPTH?

Comment: reusing code from a minimalistic example of glut. Should i not be using it in this situation?

Comment: @meriley I don't see why you should since you don't make use of the depth buffer (at least from what I can see)